# Firebase Cloud Messaging Server Account key expires

Tags: json, python-3.x, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-accounts

So I have an app which requires the **Firebase Service Account Key**. As stated in the documentation, it is a **short lived** key. So do I need to manually keep downloading the Service Account Key JSON file every time it expires?

1.This is the code I am using to extract the token from the JSON file.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']
def _get_access_token():
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        '{valid_path/file.json}', SCOPES)
    access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
    return access_token_info.access_token
```

2.The link is : https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{valid_project_id}/messages:send

3.`Content-Type : application/json; UTF-8`

4.`Authorization : Bearer *access_token_returned_in_step_1*`

5.Body

```
{
   "message":{
      "name":"name_field",
      "android":{
         "ttl":"81000s",
         "data":{
            "Name":"Z",
            "Surname":"Z"
         },
         "notification":{
            "title":"Hello",
            "body":"World"
         }
      },
      "topic":"test_topic"
   }
}
```

6. **Works perfectly well for some time**. And then,

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":401,
      "message":"Request had invalid authentication credentials. 
    Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid 
    authentication credential. See 
    https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole- 
   project.",
      "status":"UNAUTHENTICATED"
   }
}
```

7. When I **download the Service Account Key JSON file again** and run the same procedure again, **it works**.

**So, is there a way around manually downloading the Service Account Key JSON file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was **reusing** the access token extracted from the service_account.json file and pasting it into Postman for testing purposes. That was the issue. The token needs to be generated every time one needs to send messages via FCM. So, **step 1** ie. **_get_access_token()** needs to be executed every time before sending an FCM notification / data message. **Step 1** must be communicating with FCM to retrieve the latest valid token.